# How does an index greater than 1 affect this arithmatic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was wondering how the starting index affects this arithmatic series and series in general when using the formulas:

[image]

$\displaystyle=2\times\left(\frac{41\times40}2\right)-1$

$\displaystyle=1640-1$

$\displaystyle=1639$

if the index starts at 3 instead of say 1, does this affect the answer?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please state it more carefully. Also, you may look at my answer; is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I've uploaded the image of the question since I'm unsure how to format it correctly. I am basically asking if my answer is correct, as I'm used to dealing with the i=1 not i=3 and I was wondering how it affects the answer?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please take a look. Now, it should not be that hard to use it for your purposes. Hope I helped :)

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to note that $\sum_{i= 3}^{40} (2i- 1)$ is exactly the same as $\sum_{i= 1}^{40} (2i- 1)$ with the first two terms, i= 1 and i= 2, removed.  Of course, if i= 1, 2i-1= 1 and if i=2, 2i- 1= 3.  That is $\sum_{i= 3}^{40} (2i- 1)= \sum_{i= 1}^{40} (2i- 1)- 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=3}^{40}(2i-1)&=\left(\sum_{i=3}^{40}2i\right)-\left(\sum_{i=3}^{40}1\right)\\
&=2(3+4+\dotsb+40)-(\underbrace{1+1+\dotsb+1}_\textrm{38 of these})\\
&=2\big((1+2+3+4+\dotsb+40)-(1+2)\big)-(\underbrace{1+1+\dotsb+1}_\textrm{38 of these})\\
&=2\Bigg(\left(\frac{40\times41}{2}\right)-(1+2)\Bigg)-(38)\\
&=2\left(\frac{40\times41}{2}-3\right)-(38)\\
&=2(820-3)-38\\
&=1596
\end{align}

Comment: The reason that there are 38 one's is because $\{3,4,\dots,39,40\}$ is 38 numbers. ($\{1,2,3,4,\dots,39,40\}$ is 40 numbers—$\{3,4,\dots,39,40\}$ is just what you get when you take off the $1$ and the $2$.)

Comment: Can I ask the reason for the - (1+2)? Not sure I quite understand.

Comment: The _main_ issue is the $(3+4+\dotsb+40)$. We don't know how to sum that. But we _do_ know how to sum $(1+2+3+4+\dotsb+40)\ $ ! Now, note that our original sum $(3+4+\dotsb+40)$ is the same thing as $(1+2+3+4+\dotsb+40)$, _but with the $1$ and $2$ missing_. So, I'm subtracting off the $1$ and the $2$.

Comment: Another example: What is $(25+26+\dotsb+75)$? Well, that's $(1+2+\dotsb+75)-(1+2+\dotsb+24)$ (can you see why?). Using the formula, that's $\frac{75\times76}2-\frac{24\times25}{2}=2850-600=2250$.

Comment: yup! thank you for clarifying :) And also what is the reason that  the -38 is not -37 since 3 elements have been removed as we're starting at 3?

Comment: Easy mistake, but no. We're starting from 3, which means _we removed 1 and 2_ — in other words, we removed two numbers.

Comment: In my "Another example"comment, I think I meant $2850-300=2550$. Derp.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand exactly what you are asking, but I assume you are looking for something like this. The following holds true:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$
Now you have
$$
\sum_{k=\rho}^n k
=
\sum_{k=1}^n k- \sum_{k=1}^{\rho-1} k
=\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{\rho(\rho-1)}{2}
=
\frac{n^2+n-\rho^2+\rho}{2}.
$$

**Edit:** After your clarification, you may use the fact that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)=2\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n k\Bigg) - n.
$$

Comment: Your last calculation is not correct. Check it again.

Comment: Thanks @mathlove, sorry I cannot see right now... What is it?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=\rho}^{n}k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k-\sum_{k=1}^{\rho\color{red}{-1}}k.$$

Comment: @mathlove Oh, yes, thanks a lot, didn't notice that! (Is it correct now, right? How about the edit?) Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let us calculate the following sum where $2\le m\le 40$ ($m=3$ in your case):
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=\color{red}{m}}^{40}(2i-1)&=\sum_{i=1}^{40}(2i-1)-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}(2i-1)\\&=2\cdot\frac{40\cdot 41}{2}-40-2\cdot\frac{(m-1)m}{2}+(m-1)\\&=1600-(m-1)^2.\end{align}$$

As you can see, the result contains $m$. This means $m$ does affect the result.

P.S. Your answer is not corrrect. Set $m=3$ in the above result to get $1596$ as the answer.